# Cannot initialize type 'xx' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting following error when using Union

This class is generated from database in edmx

```
class JLog : EntityObject
{
   public int Id {get;set;};
   public string LogName { get;set; };
}
```

This class is creates as needed

```
class Message : JLog
{
  public string Description {get;set;};
}
```

Here is my Query

```
var data = (from j in dbContext.anotherTable
             select new Message
              {
                 Id = j.Id,
                 LogName  = j.LogName,
                 Description = j.MessageDescription
              });
```

following query return error

```
var data2 = (from v in dbContext.JLog
            Select new jLog
            {
              Id = v.Id,
              LogName  = v.LogName   
            }).Union(data);
```

so can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you provide definition of `jLog` (or update sample to use `JLog`)?

Comment: as I said JLog is generated from database model.i am using edmx file.

Comment: But your sample show some other class... (Pasting exact sample is better than retyping)